# Set created and updated date in a Redis key-value pair with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to set the creation timestamp and the updation timestamp in a Redis item just like we have in Hibernate and Spring Data JPA but it is just setting those fields to null.

```
@CreatedDate
private Date createdAt;

@LastModifiedDate
private Date modifiedAt;
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Below is the code that I am using:

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RedisHash(value = PersistenceConstants.HASH_CART)
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @NotNull
    private long customerId;

    private List<Item> items;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedAt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Spring Data Redis does not support the `@CreatedDate` and related annotations for automatic auditing. Those annotations don't do anything on their own, they're just markers. In order for something to actually happen, there has to be a Spring component that looks for them and takes some action. For JPA/Hibernate, there is the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation that you have to use to get it working.

I don't find any reference to the auditing annotations in the [Spring Data Redis documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/), which means you probably have to implement it yourself through another mechanism. Spring Data Redis might have some callback mechanism, similar to JPA; that's where I would start with building a solution.